# R - Pipeline to add column with If Formula

Tags: r, if-statement, pipeline

I have the following dataset

```
    A   B   C   D   E   F
    Ph  St  Per PM  On  IOI
1   1   959 270 3   6   NA
2   1   959 270 3   6   0.267
3   1   960 270 3   6   0.759
4   1   960 270 3   6   0.248
5   1   961 270 3   6   0.612
6   1   961 270 3   6   0.268
7   2   962 250 11  9   0.573
8   2   962 250 11  9   0.259
9   2   962 250 11  9   0.238
10  2   963 250 11  9   0.250
11  2   963 250 11  9   0.251
12  2   963 250 11  9   0.245
13  2   963 250 11  9   0.244
14  2   964 250 11  9   0.260
15  2   964 250 11  9   0.234
16  3   965 256 11  10  0.887
17  3   965 256 11  10  0.238
18  3   965 256 11  10  0.233
19  3   965 256 11  10  0.275
```

And I would like to add a column with the following formula:

`IF(C2=C1,C2*1/F1*1000,0)` - I'm using the equivalent formulas in Excel here. That is, is the second and the first row of column `Per` are equal, apply the formula `1/IOI*1000` and continue with this throughout the whole dataset.

I was creating a pipeline for it:

```
dt <- dt %>% 
  if (lag(Per) = Per) {
    mutate(Ratio = IOI * 1/Per*1000)  
  } else {
    mutate(Ratio = 0)
  }
```

But there is clearly something wrong with my code.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Use `ifelse` inside `mutate`.  Excel uses a different syntax.  Check the online help for more details.

Comment: `df %>% mutate(res = ifelse(lag(Per) == Per, lag(Per) * 1 / IOI * 1000, 0))`

Comment: Your excel formula is `IF(C2=C1,C2*1/F1*1000,0)`. `C2` corresponds to `lag(Per)` and `F1` to `IOI`, so the right expression in R should be `lag(Per) * 1 / IOI * 1000`. The answer you have accepted is different from this. Hope that you don't mistake anything in your work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is for your reference.

```
dt <- read.csv(
text="
    Ph , St,  Per, PM,  On , IOI
   1,   959, 270, 3  , 6  , NA
   1 ,  959, 270, 3  , 6 ,  0.267
   1  , 960, 270, 3  , 6,   0.759
   1  , 960, 250, 3  , 6,   0.7
",header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

dt$Per=as.numeric(dt$Per)
dt$IOI=as.numeric(dt$IOI)


dt = dt %>% mutate( ratio= (ifelse(lag(Per) == Per ,  IOI * 1/Per*1000, 0)) )
```

result:

```
Ph  St  Per PM  On  IOI ratio
<dbl>   <int>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1   959 270 3   6   NA  NA
1   959 270 3   6   0.267   0.9888889
1   960 270 3   6   0.759   2.8111111
1   960 250 3   6   0.700   0.0000000
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply Limey. I'm getting the following result when I run your code:

`Max Sum Kurt Skew Per
[1,]  NA  NA   NA   NA  NA`

I wonder what am I missing here, since it is not adding a row into my dataframe.

Comment: Could you share the code including how the dataframe example is generated so that others and I (myself) can follow . Note that I also posted how I created the dataframe so that others and I may easily comment.

Comment: Sorry about that SBMVNO, It was my mistake. I copied your example incorrectly. This works perfectly, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Is something like that what you need?

```
dt <- read.csv(
text="Ph, St, Per, PM, On, IOI,
1, 959, 270, 3, 6, ,
1, 959, 270, 3, 6, 0.267,
1, 960, 270, 3, 6, 0.759,
1, 960, 270, 3, 6, 0.248,
1, 961, 270, 3, 6, 0.612,
1, 961, 270, 3, 6, 0.268,
2, 962, 250, 11, 9, 0.573,
2, 962, 250, 11, 9, 0.259,
2, 962, 250, 11, 9, 0.238,
2, 963, 250, 11, 9, 0.250,
2, 963, 250, 11, 9, 0.251,
2, 963, 250, 11, 9, 0.245,
2, 963, 250, 11, 9, 0.244,
2, 964, 250, 11, 9, 0.260,
2, 964, 250, 11, 9, 0.234,
3, 965, 256, 11, 10, 0.887,
3, 965, 256, 11, 10, 0.238,
3, 965, 256, 11, 10, 0.233,
3, 965, 256, 11, 10, 0.275", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)[,1:6]

dt$ratio<- ifelse(dt$Per - lag(dt$Per, n = 1) != 0, yes = 0, no = dt$IOI * 1/dt$Per*1000)
```

Comment: Thank you Antreas, but the SBMVNO provided with a good answer already